# Properties of object into a comma separated string

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, filter

I have a solution where I iterate over each object key and its values however it seems a bit "hacky" to me. Does anybody have a better solution using **ES6**, `Object.values`, or other approaches?

**Original object**

```
metrics = {
  "credit": {
    "sum": false,
    "mean": false,
    "max": true,
    "min": true,
  },
  "debit": {
    "sum": false,
    "mean": true,
    "max": true,
    "min": false,
  },
  ...
}
```

**Pretended string**

```
credit:max,credit:min,debit:mean,debit:max
```

**Current solution**

```
let string = []

Object.keys(metrics).forEach(column => {
  Object.keys(metrics[column]).forEach(metric => {
    if (metrics[column][metric]) { 
      string.push(`${column}:${metric}`)
    }
  })
})


string = string.join(',')
```

Thank you.

Comment: What's the solution you have?  Why do you think it's "hacky?"  How is the "transformed" string determined?  What _exactly_ are you trying to do?

Comment: I have updated the question. I iterate over each object and push it to a new array that later is joined. Thanks in advance @RocketHazmat.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?  Does your code give the right answer?  Can you share the code you have?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I have shared my code in the question.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?  It looks fine to me, and gets you the correct output.  I suppose you could make something with `.filter()`/`.map()`, but I don't know if it would be any "cleaner."

Comment: There's nothing wrong but I would like to have a different view on the problem if there are better possible solutions. My idea was to use `.map` to avoid mutating the string array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With using [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) one needs to *know* and provide the to be processed reference ... here `metrics` ... exactly once. Thus the implementation of all the remaining code does not need to make assumptions about this reference's name but just about this data-reference's structure and how to [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#How_reduce_works) it ...

```js
const metrics = {
  "credit": {
    "sum": false,
    "mean": false,
    "max": true,
    "min": true,
  },
  "debit": {
    "sum": false,
    "mean": true,
    "max": true,
    "min": false,
  },
};

console.log(
  Object
    .entries(metrics)
    .reduce((list, [key, obj]) => [

      ...list,
      ...Object
        .entries(obj)
        .reduce((list, [value, bool]) =>

          (bool && [...list, `${ key }:${ value }`]) || list,
          []
        )
    ], []).join(',')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```